# Why actionButton pressed event does not work with dynamic UI in a nested module?

Tags: r, shiny

Here are a **nested module** inside a **container module**. The nested module defines only an `outputUI` and renders the UI with an `actionButton` and then adds an `observeEvent` to the button:

```
library(shiny)
## NESTED MODULE
nestedModuleUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  uiOutput(ns("ui_out"))
}

nestedModuleServer <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      ns <- NS(id)
    
      output$ui_out <- renderUI({
        actionButton(ns("button"), "Press me")
      })
      
      observeEvent(input$button ,  print("button pressed!"))
    }
  )
}

## CONTAINER MODULE
containerModuleUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  nestedModuleUI(ns("nested"))
}

containerModuleServer <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      nestedModuleServer("nested")
    }
  )
}

## Application
ui <-  containerModuleUI("container")

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  containerModuleServer("container")
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

### Issue

Nothing happens when the button is pressed...

---

One can note **two facts** here:

### First fact

The nested module works when not nested, just change the main app this way to check this first fact:

```
## Application
ui <-  nestedModuleUI("nested")

server <- function(input, output, session) nestedModuleServer("nested")

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

### Second fact

If the button is not created dynamically the minimal example also works, change the nested module this way to check the second fact:

```
## NESTED MODULE
nestedModuleUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  actionButton(ns("button"), "Press me")
}

nestedModuleServer <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      ns <- NS(id)
        
      observeEvent(input$button ,  print("button pressed!"))
    }
  )
}
```

---

### Question

What is missing here to make the event detected when the button is created dynamically AND the module is nested?

---

##### Version

R 4.2.2
Shiny 1.7.4.1

Comment: @YBS Have you `button clicked` on your console? What is you version of R and shiny?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that using `ns <- NS(id)` does not and can't account for that the module `"nested"` is nested inside the module `"container"`. As a result the `actionButton` is created in a wrong namespace, i.e. it is created in the namespace `"nested"` whereas it should be created in `"container-nested"`.

Instead, when using `renderUI` in a module you have to get the namespace from the `session` object, i.e. use `ns <- session$ns`. See the section **Using renderUI within modules** in [Modularizing Shiny app code](https://shiny.posit.co/r/articles/improve/modules/).

In the code below I added two `print` statements to the `observeEvent` to show the difference.

```
library(shiny)

nestedModuleUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  uiOutput(ns("ui_out"))
}

nestedModuleServer <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      ns <- session$ns

      output$ui_out <- renderUI({
        actionButton(ns("button"), "Press me")
      })

      observeEvent(input$button, {
        print(
          paste0(
            "ns <- NS(id); ns(\"button\"): ",
            NS(id, "button")
          )
        )
        print(
          paste0(
            "ns <- session$ns; ns(\"button\"): ",
            session$ns("button")
          )
        )
        print("button pressed!")
      })
    }
  )
}

## CONTAINER MODULE
containerModuleUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  nestedModuleUI(ns("nested"))
}

containerModuleServer <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      nestedModuleServer("nested")
    }
  )
}

ui <- containerModuleUI("container")

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  containerModuleServer("container")
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by @stefan:

`session$ns` is mandatory if you want to use nested modules which use dynamic UI with `uiOutput`

#### Minimal example with one proper working button

```
## NESTED MODULE
nestedModuleUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  shiny::uiOutput(ns("ui_out"))
}

nestedModuleServer <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {

      output$ui_out <- shiny::renderUI({
        list(
          shiny::actionButton(session$ns("well_formed"), "I work"),
          shiny::actionButton(NS(id, "bad_formed"), "I do nothin'")
        )
      })

      observeEvent(input$well_formed,  print("button pressed!"))
      observeEvent(input$bad_formed,  print("button pressed!"))
    }
  )
}

## CONTAINER MODULE
containerModuleUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  nestedModuleUI(ns("nested"))
}

containerModuleServer <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      nestedModuleServer("nested")
    }
  )
}

## Application
library(shiny)
ui <-  containerModuleUI("container")

server <- function(input, output, session) containerModuleServer("container")

shinyApp(ui, server)
```